# Why is my transform.position setter called via OnMouseDown() so slow?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following method in my code:

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    cube.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
}
```

When clicked on the gameObject, this method is called. It takes long to change the position of the cube (not more than a second, but still long, at least half a second). It does affect the user playing experience.

If I don't change the position of the cube, but for example its material, it is still slow. So I do know that this doesn't have to do with the line in my OnMouseDown() event.

Note however that I do have around 35 imported 3D meshes in my Scene, as well as over 50 primitive game objects. Does this have anything to do with the method being slow? Because when I make an empty Unity project with just 2 gameObjects, the method is fast.

Is it because of my full scene? Any ideas? Thanks!

If someone knows how to speed it up as well, I'd love to know!

EDIT: If I remove all my 3D meshes, the method is fast...

Comment: Hmm... this should be instant. What's your framerate?

Comment: It's around 10 fps.

Comment: I guess we need way more information. Could you tell us more about your hardware specs, are the 3D objects high poly? Could you also drop a screenshot of your profiler? Maybe it's because of having low-end specs with high poly objects that make 10fps lag? Last one only if you have rly high poly probably.

Comment: It sounds like you are getting a lot of input lag due to your machine specs, do other input operations take as much time? My daughter was playing the walking dead (telltale one) on her terribly under powered laptop and there was at least half a second input lag (even though the frame rate wasn't the worst I've seen)

Answer (score 1):

Unless your transfom tree is hundereds of children deep, this should be pretty much instant, its one of the things Unity has been designed to do quickly, so I think this has to do with the meshes you import. The should not have too many verticies, too many materials, and too many objects.
You can try to go through you objects with a 3D editor package (blender?) and combine the chunks into single objects.

If unity lags when you move an object, it may mean it has too many individual transforms to process. If your scene is intense you can gain a lot of performance by 'baknig' it, combining individual objects into larger meshes (those live on the gpu and cost gpu time not cpu time).

It is also possible that one or more of the meshes you imported has too many verts/triangles. If you currently have 10fps you may want to target having lighter meshes, and as few seperate GameObjects as possible (ideally you want the environment to be just a few combined meshes (to enable culling), not thousands of objects)

Answer (score 0):

### solution

Try to check if there are heavy materials are used that can slow the procedure. The  game becomes slow when the objects are being added in the project and it destroy the overall efficiency of the game . It happens with me when i used too heavy models in the project the overall speed of the game is decreased . I replaced them with lightweight models of truck and issue was resolved .

Comment: Doesn't make sense, the user isn't moving an object, just setting the position upon mouse click which should be instantaneous.

Comment: Oh sorry, The i misunderstood the question and thanks for remove my misunderstanding , I hope now the answer will make 100% sense